# React looping over every value that a state variable has had before rendering on the final value

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have a class that listens for clicks on a map, and when a click has been detected, it is added to an array `routeWayPoints`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Tab from "./Tab";

import RouteWayPointsTable from "./RouteWayPointsTable";

import { map, removeFromTheMap, addToTheMap } from "../javascript/mapInterprater";

function RouteAnalysisTab() {
  const [routeWayPoints, setRouteWayPoints] = useState([]);

  function beginPlottingRoute() {
    setRouteWayPoints([]);
  }


  map.on("click", onMapClick);

  function onMapClick(event) {
    if (isRouteActive) {
      setRouteWayPoints(routeWayPoints.concat(event.latlng));
    }
  }

  return (
    <Tab id="analyse-route" title="Analyse route" className="data-display__tab-content">
      <h3>Analyse route</h3>
      {!isRouteActive && routeWayPoints.length > 0 && (
        <button className="button" id="new-route-button" type="button" onClick={() => beginPlottingRoute()}>
          Plot new route
        </button>
      )}
      <div className="data-display__tab-content--route-analysis">
        {!isRouteActive && routeWayPoints.length === 0 && (
          <button className="data-display__button--home" id="plot-route-button" type="button" onClick={() => beginPlottingRoute()}>
            Plot a route
          </button>
        )}
        <RouteWayPointsTable routeWayPoints={routeWayPoints} />
      </div>
    </Tab>
  );
}

export default RouteAnalysisTab;
```

I pass the array to the `RouteWayPointTable` component and attempt to loop over each item and create a row in the table using the `RouteWayPointRow` component.

```
import React from "react";

import RouteWayPointRow from "../components/RouteWayPointRow";

function RouteWayPointsTable(props) {
  return (
    <div id="route-analysis">
      <table className="data-display__waypoint-table" id="analyse-route-waypoints">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="data-display__waypoint-table--way-point-col">Way point</th>
            <th className="data-display__waypoint-table--lat-col">Latitude</th>
            <th className="data-display__waypoint-table--lng-col">Longitude</th>
            <th className="data-display__waypoint-table--remove-col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.routeWayPoints.map((wayPoint, index) => {
            return <RouteWayPointRow wayPoint={wayPoint} index={index} key={index} />;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RouteWayPointsTable;
```

Now the rows are being displayed, but I'm observing some strange behaviour I didn't expect.

As I add points to the array, React is iterating over every state the array existed in before it renders the latest point, so the amount of time it takes to update the table is getting exponentially longer as it has to perform more loops over the array every time a new point has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was that I had declared the map listener inside the component, and so a new listener was being created each time I clicked on the map which cause React to re-render the DOM

```
function RouteAnalysisTab() {
  const [routeWayPoints, setRouteWayPoints] = useState([]);

  function beginPlottingRoute() {
    setRouteWayPoints([]);
  }


  map.on("click", onMapClick);
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but removing the listener before creating it did the trick:

```
  map.off("click");
  map.on("click", onMapClick);
```